# How to access variable value inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have searched on the website for solutions, but I have had no luck. 
I need to make this data global. My code is present below:

```js
     function val() {
            var plans = @json($plans);
            var id = document.getElementById("plan_id").value;
            plans.forEach(function(element) {
                if (id == element.id) {
                    var  i = element.amount;
                    return i;
                }
            });

        }
        var obj =  val()
        console.log(obj)
```

After I log that, it wont give any values but if I log inside the foreach, I will get the amount. Pls how can I access data inside foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I have fixed my issue, but I follow another process.

I actually get the amount using onclick

Comment: Can you edit your main post or this answer with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to return a value if you want to log it outside like this.

```
function val() {
  const plans = @json($plans);
  const id = document.getElementById("plan_id").value;
  return plans
    .filter(element => id === element.id)
    .map(element => element.amount);

}

const obj = val()
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: It's not still log out the amount

Comment: I don't understand, what is it currently logging and what do you want it to log?

Comment: the val() is listening to onchange event, so I need a way when I select and option, the amount will change

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from the function and `return` inside `forEach` is always `undefined`. Use `find`

```js
function val() {
  var plans = @json($plans);
  var id = document.getElementById("plan_id").value;
  return plans.find(element => id === element.id).amount;

}
var obj = val()
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: the val() is listening to onchange event, so I need a way when I select an option, the amount will change

Answer (score 0):

This would on change get the amountValue from based on what ID you have selected.

```js
var amountValue = null;

function val() {
    var plans = @json($plans);
    var id = document.getElementById("plan_id").value;
    for (i = 0; i < plans.length; i++) {
        if (id === plans[i].id) {
            amountValue = plans[i].amount;
            return amountValue;
        }
    }
}
var obj = val()
console.log(obj)
```